# Merging unsorted collections

Tags: algorithm, array-merge

Assume I have two collections:

A = [John, Mary, Frank, Isabel, Teresa]

B = [Madison, John, Frank, Isabel, Bob]

The algorithm should produce the following result:

MERGE = [Madison, John, Mary, Frank, Isabel, Teresa, Bob]

(although it's also fine if Teresa and Bob are switched)

In other words, the algorithm should use the existing ordering of the two input collections to create a merged collection. There is a theoretically unlimited amount of possible elements, and there is no "master" list from which the order of the elements can be taken.

For my use case, the input collections will be reasonably small (typically less than 50 items), and the majority of items will be the same between the collections, although that's not guaranteed.

Is this a known type of algorithm? I have been searching for merging algorithms, but most talk about ordered lists and performance optimizations thereof.

----- EDIT ------

A few more examples:

first additional example:
A = [John, Mary, Frank, Isabel, Teresa, Robert, Bob, Anna, Tessa, Philip]
B = [John, Mary, Robert, Bob, Philip, Nicholas]
MERGE = [John, Mary, Frank, Isabel, Teresa, Robert, Bob, Anna, Tessa, Philip, Nicholas]

(so the algorithm should infer that Nicholas should be positioned after Philip, because that's also the case in collection B)

second additional example:
A = [John, Mary, Frank, Isabel, Teresa, Robert, Bob, Anna, Tessa, Philip]
B = [Betty, John, Bob, Philip, Nicholas, Boris]
MERGE = [Betty, John, Mary, Frank, Isabel, Teresa, Robert, Bob, Anna, Tessa, Philip, Nicholas, Boris]

(so the algorithm should infer that Betty should be positioned before John, and Nicholas & Boris after Philip)

Comment: Would `B.zip(A).flatten.uniq.compact` do the trick for you?  I inferred from your example that you wanted the first element from each, then the second, etc., hence the zip.  Otherwise, `(B + A).uniq`.

Comment: Simply flattening is not a solution, although I completely see why you are suggesting it. The example collections were probably a bit too simplistic, sorry!

Comment: As regards the correct order in confusing examples: this will not be an issue, as the majority of the items will be the same between the collections (the collections are actually small mutations of each other). If there is ambiguity about the correct ordering, then any output would be fine for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of topological sort, with the relation `x < y` if `x` appears before `y` in either list.

This algorithm produces the merged list whenever that's possible:

- If the heads of the two lists are the same, add that head to the result, and remove it from both lists.
- If the head of the either list is not in the other list, add it to the result, and remove it from the list it's in.
- Otherwise, there's no result that preserves the order of the elements in both lists.

You can make this efficient -- that is, O(n) time -- by keeping a set for each lists for the elements remaining in the list, or building a map for each list that maps elements to their index in the list.

Comment: This is the correct answer assuming the elements are distinct within each list, which seems to be the case. If the input lists can contain duplicates (i.e. an element which occurs more than once in one of the lists), then it's the [shortest common supersequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem), which (for two lists) can be solved in O(n^2) time by dynamic programming, or constructed from a longest common subsequence.

Comment: Intriguing way to look at it, I had not really thought of it. Very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you want to merge two arrays while protecting their order and remove the consecutive duplicates.

In order to do that, we can simply loop the bigger array and at every loop we can control the list length, consecutive duplicate etc...

Code:

```py
A = ["John", "Mary", "Frank", "Isabel", "Teresa"]
B = ["Madison", "John", "Frank", "Isabel", "Bob"]

# Determine the bigger array length.
loop_count = len(A)
if len(B) > len(A):
    loop_count = len(B)

# Loop the arrays and append to merged array if not out of index,
# or not consecutive duplicate.
merged = []   
for i in range(0, loop_count):
    if i < len(A):
        if len(merged) == 0 or merged[-1] != A[i]:
            merged.append(A[i])
    if i < len(B):
        if len(merged) == 0 or merged[-1] != B[i]:
            merged.append(B[i])

print(merged)
```

Output: `['John', 'Madison', 'Mary', 'John', 'Frank', 'Isabel', 'Teresa', 'Bob']`

Its not the perfect solution, there is better ways to optimize it but since you said your arrays are reasonably small, it should be fine enough.